# Returning many-to-many results with LINQ in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm struggling to understand LINQ syntax and how to use it with many-to-many relationships in a database.  In my example project I'm modeling cars and maintenance you can do to a car.  So I have 3 tables:

1. Cars (information about a car that a user adds)
2. Services (reference info only)
3. CarServices (stores what services have been done on a car)

On the website, I'm displaying info from all 3 of these tables so I've created a view model, CarsIndexViewModel, to hold a Car and its associated CarServices.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1900, 2018)]
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CarService> CarServices { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CarService> CarServices { get; set; }

}

public class CarService
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Service")]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Service")]
    public DateTime ServiceDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }

    public bool HasReceipt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Mileage At Time of Service")]
    public int Mileage { get; set; }

    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

and the view model:

```
public class CarsIndexViewModel
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CarService> Services { get; set; }
}
```

I've been able to return *all* of the services and their information by using this code in my controller:

```
var query = (
            from car in _context.Cars
            select new CarsIndexViewModel()
            {
                Car = car,
                Services = car.CarServices
            }).ToList();

return View(query);
```

What I cannot figure out is how to only return CarServices that meet certain criteria.  For example, what if I only want to show CarServices from the most recent date?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show most recent services:

```
var query = (from car in _context.Cars
             select new CarsIndexViewModel()
             {
                 Car = car,
                 Services = car.CarServices
                               .OrderByDescending(cs => cs.ServiceDate)
                               .Take(5) // only 5 most recent
                               .ToList()
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. A couple possibilities to get what you are talking about (show CarServices from the most recent date) is this:

**Last `n` recent services:**

```
var n = 4;
var query = (
        from car in _context.Cars
        select new CarsIndexViewModel()
        {
            Car = car,
            AllServices = car.CarServices,
            RecentServices = car.CarServices.OrderBy(x => ServiceDate).Take(n)
        }).ToList();
```

**Recent services after a given date:**

```
var recentThreshold = new DateTime(2017,01,01);
var query = (
        from car in _context.Cars
        select new CarsIndexViewModel()
        {
            Car = car,
            AllServices = car.CarServices,
            RecentServices = car.CarServices.Where(x => ServiceDate > recentThreshhold)
        }).ToList();
```

**Recent services that all happened on the last day that any service was given:**

```
var latestServiceDates = (
        from car in _context.Cars
        select new KeyValuePair<int, DateTime>()
        {
            Key = car.id,
            Value = car.CarServices.OrderByDescending(x => ServiceDate).First()
        }).ToList();
var query = (
        from car in _context.Cars
        select new CarsIndexViewModel()
        {
            Car = car,
            AllServices = car.CarServices,
            RecentServices = car.CarServices.Where(x => ServiceDate = latestServiceDates.First(y => y.Key == x.id))
        }).ToList();
```

It just depends what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  What I want is similar to your second example, but I want recentThreshold to be equal to the most recent date in CarServices.  For example, if the car was in the shop most recently on Feb 2nd and had an Oil Change and TIre Rotation done I would only want to return those two rows from CarServices.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I added an option that will hopefully get you what you need. I'm assumig that your `car` object has an identifier of some sort? I'm using that assumption to build a lookup table for latest service dates for each car. I used `id`. If it's named something else, you will have to use that. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Key and Value are read-only attributes of KeyValuePair, so you have to pass in those values in the constructor.  But, it looks like LINQ doesn't let you use constructors with parameters.  I tried creating an object with the id and date first, then creating the KeyValuePairs in memory which did work.  But now I get an exception that I think is from trying to combine LINQ->Object and LINQ->EF.

Comment: OK sorry about that. I wrote it and had to rush out. I should have looked up KeyValuePair more thoroughly. But the general concept should be the same. So do you have it working now, or are you still getting errors?

Comment: I think the concept is good, but I'm still stuck on this NotSupportedException when trying to run the second statement.  I think it's from trying to combine LINQ->objects in memory and LINQ->EF.  I'm considering just pulling back everything and doing this filtering after the fact with a for loop or something!